# Can I be sure about the order in a dictionary?

Tags: python, dictionary, iterable-unpacking

Can I be sure about the order in a Python dictionary?

The function `op.GetTangent(id)` returns a dictionary containing two values associated with `'vl'` and `'vr'`. I want to unpack it the lazy way.

```
vr, vl = op.GetTangent(id).values()
```

Can I be sure that `vr` and `vl` have the correct value or can there be a case where they're exchanged?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
vr, vl = map(op.GetTangent(id).get, ('vr', 'vl'))
```

Answer (score 6):

No, you should never depend on the order of the entries returned by the `values` method. You have several easy options:

- Call `sorted` on the resulting list (if the values can be sorted)
- Call `sorted` on the items and pull out the values
- Use a `collections.OrderedDict`

Comment: Given that he's just pulling the values `sorted` isn't going to help here.

Answer (score 3):

No, never.

Instead do

```
getbyname = lambda d, *kk: [d[k] for k in kk]
```

and use it as

```
vr, vl = getbyname(op.GetTangent(id), 'vr', 'vl')
```

or just do

```
d = op.GetTangent(id)
vr, vl = [d[i] for i in ('vr', 'vl')]
```

if you need it only once.

Answer (score 1):

Just for the complete avoidance of any doubt whatsoever, actual output on my system:

```
C:\Python32>python -c "print({'vr':1, 'vl':2})"
{'vr': 1, 'vl': 2}

C:\Python32>python -c "print({'vr':1, 'vl':2})"
{'vl': 2, 'vr': 1}
```

That is running Python 3.2.3 with PYTHONHASHSEED set to 'random' and different runs of identical code have different orders of items in the dictionary.